# Closed projects hidden in pydev package explorer

Tags: eclipse, pydev, perspectives

I'm using eclipse for java and python. In the pydev package explorer, I have it set to show closed projects, but hide non-pydev projects. The problem I'm having is that after I close a pydev project, it is hidden in the pydev package explorer, but not in the java perspective package explorer. If I open it again it disappears from the java perspective and appears again in pydev.

It's really a minor issue, and maybe I'm just missing something really basic, but is there a way to get python projects to show up only in the pydev perspective, even when they are closed?

To reiterate, in the "Customize view..." menu for the pydev package explorer, I have it set correctly to hide non-pydev projects, but show closed projects. I think it might just not be able to tell if closed projects are associated with python or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last sentence is correct.  It does not know anything about a closed project.